# How to update the bundle.js file in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having a hard time finding a way to update the bundle.js file, which is a combination of many front end jsx files merged together. Changes are only recognized/ taken into effect when done in the bundle.js file. Is there a npm command or something to update the bundle.js file? Or a technology I'm not aware of?
I'm taking over from other developers.

Thank you for reading/ your suggestions.

Comment: Can you describe your project? How are you bundling it? webpack or anything else ? how is your project setup ?

Comment: It's a separate API and then a front end web application, we use webpack. I have taken over from another developer who left but I'm justva student, my knowledge on it isn't great.

Comment: Can you share the package.json or the entire code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue has been solved**, I needed to have it running on a Linux  system, thanks all for the input.

Comment: Great. But solution doesn't seem logical. What was the platform specific stuff that made it to bundle work only on linux?

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I run a copy of the project on Linux it just works. I'm sorry I don't have a better understanding of it at this time.

Comment: Also, the previous developers told me recently it was developed using Linux.